# Matrices with large diagonals and their inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

I am looking at a sequence of matrices $M_n \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ that satisfy the following properties:

1. $M_n = A_n^T B_n A_n$, where $A_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ is full rank and $B_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric positive definite for all $n$
2. All $p$ diagonal elements of $M_n$ diverge as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Through simulations, it appears that $M_n^{-1}$ approaches the zero $p \times p$ matrix. Can I deduce this from these two properties alone?  Property 2 only implies that the largest eigenvalue of $M_n$ diverges, not necessarily the smallest (which is what we need).

Comment: I don't think that is true. Pick $n=2$, $A_n=Id_2$ and $$B_n=\begin{pmatrix} n & n-1/n^2 \\ n-1/n^2 & n \end{pmatrix}.$$ The diagonal elements blow up and it is symmetric. Furthermore, $det(B_n), tr(B_n)>0,$ hence, $B_n$ is positive definite. On the other hand, $det(B_n)=n^2-(n-1/n^2)^2 = 2/n+1/n^4.$ Thus, the lowest eigenvalue goes to zero.

Comment: Oh, I did not see it while typing. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the top $p$ rows of $A_n$ form the identity matrix, the rest being $0$.
$B_n$ is any positive definite $n \times n$ matrix.  Then $M_n$ is the top left $p \times p$
block of $B_n$, which can be any $p \times p$ positive definite matrix.  So you seem to be asserting that if $M_n$ is a sequence of positive definite $n \times n$ matrices
whose diagonal elements go to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$, $M_n^{-1} \to 0$.
This is certainly false.  Try the case $p=2$ with $$M_n = \pmatrix{n & n-1\cr n-1 & n\cr},\ M_n^{-1} = \pmatrix{\frac{n}{2n-1} & \frac{1-n}{2n-1}\cr \frac{1-n}{2n-1} & \frac{n}{2n-1}\cr} $$